# Is it possible to directly convert JS to a hex-file for the BBC Micro:bit?

Tags: javascript, blockly, bbc-microbit

I am trying to develop a simple JavaScript/Blockly IDE for programming the Micro:bit. Similar to how you write some JavaScript in MakeCode, click download and then MakeCode gives you a hex-file for the micro:bit, I would like to generate exactly the same hex-files from exactly the same JavaScript. I haven't been able to find any concrete information.

**Is there a JS library or some sort that can handle that conversion?**

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've already looked into it, but sadly it's not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You ca use the MakeCode command line node application to build a project locally from Typ Script to the hex file. More info: https://makecode.com/cli

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out!